# Tx LPC2148 with Xbee in API mode with Rx Xbee with Relay not works

Tags: api, xbee

I started to work on lpc2148 with xbee series 2.
On the transmitting side i am using lpc2148 with xbee  coordinator in API mode, 
and Rx side i am using xbee on Shield in router AT mode.
I want XBee to activate a D3 pin, which could be used to turn on relay on Rx side

API frame format as below code using c program .

enter code here

```
#define Delimeter    0x7E 

void  Init_UART1(void)                 //This function setups UART1
{  
unsigned int Baud16;
U1LCR = 0x83;                   // DLAB = 1
Baud16 = (Fpclk / 16) / UART_BPS;  
U1DLM = Baud16 / 256;                           
U1DLL = Baud16 % 256;                       
U1LCR = 0x03;
} 

void main() { 

 Init_UART1();
 LED1_ON();
 setRemoteState(0x5);//AD3 config DOUT HIGH
 Delay(25);
 LED1_OFF();
 setRemoteState(0x4);//AD3 config DOUT LOW
 Delay(25);

 void setRemoteState (char value) {

 UART1_Write(Delimeter);//start byte
 UART1_Write(0);//high part of length
 UART1_Write(0X10);//low part of length
 UART1_Write(0X17);//remote AT command 
 UART1_Write(0X0);//frame id 0 for no reply
 UART1_Write(0X0);
 UART1_Write(0X0);
 UART1_Write(0X0);
 UART1_Write(0X0);
 UART1_Write(0X0);
 UART1_Write(0X0);
 UART1_Write(0XFF);// broadcast
 UART1_Write(0XFF);// broadcast
 UART1_Write(0XFF);
 UART1_Write(0XFE);
 UART1_Write(0X02);//apply changes immediately on remote
 UART1_Write('D');//writing on AD3 pin
 UART1_Write('3');
 UART1_Write(value);
 sum = 0x17 + 0xFF + 0xFF + 0xFF + 0xFE + 0x02 + 'D' + '3' + value;
 UART1_Write(0xFF - (0xFF & sum));//checksum

 Delay(25);
 }  
 }
```

i am not able to get any communication or data on my Rx side. D3 pinout volage is still low.
Please guide on this point...

This program is working fine with arduino using Serial.write Function.

Regards,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the correct baud rate?  Are you sure you've connected TX/RX correctly and haven't crossed them?  If you have hardware flow control enabled, is the RTS signal into the XBee asserted?  Is the XBee module powering up and receiving enough current?

If you monitor the XBee transmit signal on another device (computer via FTDI's TTL-to-USB cable) are you seeing bytes at startup (I believe it sends a Modem Status during it's startup)?  If you monitor the LPC2148 transmit signal, are you seeing the byte stream you think you're sending (confirming that you're driving UART1 correctly)?

Can you tell if the XBee module is receiving your requests, perhaps by toggling `ATD0` between high and low output and checking with an LED or scope?  Do you have any hardware you can use to monitor the serial stream between the two devices to see if it's sending the bytes you think you're sending?  Are you sure it's calculating the correct checksum (dump the bytes somehow and try running them through X-CTU to see if they work).

If you're going to be doing a lot of communications between the LPC2148 and the XBee module, you might want to try porting this [Open Source ANSI C XBee Host Library](https://github.com/tomlogic/xbee_ansic_library) to the platform.  It includes multiple layers of XBee frame processing that should reduce the amount of software you need to write.

Comment: Although it doesn't answer the question directly, I feel this guides the OP in narrowing down the cause of their problem.  Another user searching SO for a similar issue would benefit from the same instructions.  It started out as a comment, but quickly grew too large.  Should I break it down into multiple comments and delete this as an answer?